# How can I display icon in datagridview specific cell instead of True or false of boolean type, in C# winform?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

How can I display icon in datagridview specifik cell instead of True or false of boolean type?
I have those two images in my Project Resources (I don't know if its is best place to store them). It's like thumbs up and thumbs down images. 
Thank you in advance!
Here is my code I'am trying fix but offcourse do not working

```
var result = (from u in db.Analys
              join d in db.Department on u.deptId equals d.deptId 
              select new
             {
               AnalysId = u.Id
               Department = d.DepartmenName,                                           
               Accept= u.accept == true ? Resources.thumbsUp : Resources.thumbsDown   

           }).ToList();
           if (result != null)
           {
             daraGridViewResult.DataSource = null;
             daraGridViewResult.DataSource = result;

           }
```

Comment: See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-display-images-in-cells-of-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control)

Comment: The [DataGridView.CellPainting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellpainting?view=net-5.0) event is good for doing this. The @CR0N0S.LXIII answer will work. In that event, you can use the `daraGridViewResult.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value` to decide which Resources.thumbsUp or thungsDown to use.

Comment: The reason you might want to use the DataGridView.CellPainting instead of @Cid's DataGridViewImageColumn method is the CellPainting will work with all DataGridView DataColumn Types.

Answer (score 1):

On the CellPainting event of your grid, you can add a code like this:

```
 e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All);

 var w = Properties.Resources.yes.Width;
 var h = Properties.Resources.yes.Height;
 var x = e.CellBounds.Left + (e.CellBounds.Width - w) / 2;
 var y = e.CellBounds.Top + (e.CellBounds.Height - h) / 2;

 e.Graphics.DrawImage(image, new Rectangle(x, y, w, h));
```

where "image" is the image you want to display instead of "true" or "false".

Keep in mind that this code will execute for every single cell in the datagrid. You need to control that this only applies to cells on your boolean column.

EDIT:

```
 if (e.ColumnIndex == yourGrid.Columns["Accept"].Index)
 {
      e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All);

      var w = Properties.Resources.yes.Width;
      var h = Properties.Resources.yes.Height;
      var x = e.CellBounds.Left + (e.CellBounds.Width - w) / 2;
      var y = e.CellBounds.Top + (e.CellBounds.Height - h) / 2;

      e.Graphics.DrawImage(image, new Rectangle(x, y, w, h));
 } //if
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I do not have only one Column, I have multiple columns. I want to Display only in that specific column with name "Accept"

Comment: You have to check that e.ColumnIndex is equal to the index of the column you want to paint

Comment: thank you again. But stil not showing images, I think because I have two different images, deponds on if it's true then I want to display Resources.thumbsUp but if it's false then I want to display Resources.thumbsDown. I mean condition of       Accept= u.accept == true ? Resources.thumbsUp : Resources.thumbsDown. Those two images  thumbsUp.jpg and thumbsDown I have them in Resources. Sorry I could'nt response you becouse I hade a cold. Thank you again

Comment: @CR0N0S.LXIII - Needed to make it work:  `e.Handled = true;` otherwise successive Painting clears the painted image